# Display Ads inside ion-list in ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have a simple content app built in Ionic and Cordova. I am using the cordova admob pro plugin, but my oproblem is that my banner ad shows inside ion-list, which from my understanding is not good for Google's ad policy.

```
this.admob.createBanner( { adId: this.adId, adSize:'SMART_BANNER', autoShow: true, position: this.admob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, overlap: false, isTesting:false });
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: this.admob.createBanner( {
      adId: this.adId,
      adSize:'SMART_BANNER',
      autoShow: true,
      position: this.admob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
      overlap: false,
      isTesting:false 
        });

@Eric Hauenstein